# Ec2 instance RDP suddenly unable to connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rdp

I have created 2 EC2 instances in AWS

I have connected with RDP and added some data for the last 3 days working fine but suddenly my one instance is unable to connect another one is working fine.

I have checked the working status in EC2 showing the status check is a success.

Comment: Have you stopped/started instance? Have you checked instance IP address?

Comment: Yes. ip is changed default i have tried with new one  Instance state = running

Comment: It is also possible that your own (home?) IP address has changed. Check the configuration of the Security Group associated with the EC2 instance. When it fails, does it fail immediately (suggesting incorrect credentials), or does it take some time before it fails (suggesting a lack of network connectivity)?